# How to get the little arrow Finder puts on aliases?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Does anyone know how to get the little arrow Finder puts on aliases?

I currently use the following to get icon for display.

```
 [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[item fullPath]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path of the .icon file is at `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/AliasBadgeIcon.icns`

So use someting similar to

`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[item "/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/AliasBadgeIcon.icns"]]`

Comment: This answers the question I actually asked. What I want to know is how do I get the Folder + Arrow image (or how to combine the arrow with the original icon.